# Like terms involving exponents

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Can someone explain how this works like I'm 5? I understand $2^{k+1}$ and $2^{k+1}$ are both like terms but why does it result in $2\cdot 2^{k+1}$? I thought it would be $4^{2k}+2$.

\begin{align*}
2^{k + 1} - 2 + 2^{k + 1} & = 2 \cdot 2^{k + 1} - 2\\
                          & = 2^{k + 2} - 2\\
                          & = 2^{(k + 1) + 1} - 2
\end{align*}

Comment: $$...=2^{k+1}+2^{k+1}-2=2×2^{k+1}-2$$

Comment: $2^a\times 2^b=2^{a+b}$.  So $2\times 2^{k+1}=2^1\times 2^{k+1}=2^{k+2}$.

Comment: It’s $x+x=2x$, but $x=2^{2k+1}$…

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please type in your formula using MathJax instead of linking an image. You can find a tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $2^{k + 1} + 2^{k+1} = 2\cdot 2^{k+1} = 2 \cdot\underbrace{2\cdot 2\cdot ........ \cdot 2}_{k+1\ 2s}= \underbrace{ 2 \cdot\underbrace{2\cdot 2\cdot ........ \cdot 2}_{k+1\ 2s}}_{1+(k+1)\ 2s}= \underbrace{2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2 \cdot..... \cdot 2}_{k+2\ 2s}=2^{k+2}$....  It can't be $4^{2k+2}$ because $4^{2k+2} = \underbrace{4\cdot 4\cdot ..... \cdot 4}_{2k+2\ 4s}=\underbrace{(2\times 2)\cdot (2\times 2) \cdot .... \cdot(2\times 2)}_{2k+2\text{ pairs of }2s}=\underbrace{2\cdot 2\cdot2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot2\cdot....\cdot 2\cdot 2}_{4k+4\ 2s}$ a completely different result.